# sigsegv on CloseHandle on an open pipe

Tags: c, winapi

I'm getting a sigsegv on CloseHandle(pipe_settings->hPipe);  I'm using threads in this example, too, which I don't think has to do with anything because the pipe is opened and closed in the same thread.

The pipe handle also seems to be valid.  Something like: 0xcc.
The event handle closes properly, too.

This is a fully working example and you should be able to just drop it into CLion and let 'er rip.  This code should be safe on any Windows installation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UNICODE

#define PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define PIPE_TIMEOUT 10000
#define PIPE_MAX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 10000
#define PIPE_CONNECT_FAIL_REPEAT_DELAY 1000
#define DUST_TEST_PIPE_NAME "\\\\.\\pipe\\DustTestPipe"
#define PIPE_TEST_TIMEOUT 100000

struct pipe_settings {
    HANDLE hPipe;
    OVERLAPPED ol;
    LPCTSTR name;
    DWORD pipe_timeout;
};

WINBOOL PipeClose(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    //Dies on CloseHandle(pipe_settings->hPipe) but not on CloseHandle(pipe_settings->ol.hEvent)
    return (CloseHandle(pipe_settings->ol.hEvent) && CloseHandle(pipe_settings->hPipe));
}

void InitializePipeSettings(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    pipe_settings->hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    pipe_settings->ol.hEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    pipe_settings->ol.Internal = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.InternalHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Offset = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.OffsetHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Pointer = NULL;
}

DWORD PipeConnectToClient(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    HANDLE h;
    DWORD err;

    InitializePipeSettings(pipe_settings);

    for(int x = 0; x < PIPE_MAX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT; x += PIPE_CONNECT_FAIL_REPEAT_DELAY)
    {

        h = CreateFile(
                pipe_settings->name,
                GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                NULL
        );

        err = GetLastError();

        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;

        if(err == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            //The pipe might not be open yet
            sleep(PIPE_CONNECT_FAIL_REPEAT_DELAY/1000);
            continue;
        }

        else if (err != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) {
            return err;
        }

        if (!WaitNamedPipe(pipe_settings->name, (DWORD)PIPE_MAX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT - x))
        {
            return ERROR_PIPE_BUSY;
        }
    }

    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return err;

    pipe_settings->hPipe = h;

    DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE;

    if(!SetNamedPipeHandleState(h, &dwMode, NULL, NULL))
        return GetLastError();

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD PipeListenForServerConnect(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    InitializePipeSettings(pipe_settings);

    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
            pipe_settings->name,
            PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND |    // read/write access
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,    // overlapped mode
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE |         // message-type pipe
            PIPE_READMODE_BYTE |     // message-read mode
            PIPE_WAIT,
            1,
            PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
            PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
            PIPE_TIMEOUT,
            NULL
    );

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    OVERLAPPED ol;
    //DWORD dwWait;

    ol.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if(ol.hEvent == NULL)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    if(ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, &ol) == 0)
    {
        //error should be ERROR_IO_PENDING or ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED
        DWORD err = GetLastError();

        //wait for the connection event
        if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING && err != ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED) {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(ol.hEvent, pipe_settings->pipe_timeout) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                CloseHandle(hPipe);
                CloseHandle(ol.hEvent);
                return err;
            }
        }
    }

    pipe_settings->hPipe = hPipe;
    pipe_settings->ol.Pointer = ol.Pointer;
    pipe_settings->ol.Offset = ol.Offset;
    pipe_settings->ol.Internal = ol.Internal;
    pipe_settings->ol.hEvent = ol.hEvent;
    pipe_settings->ol.InternalHigh = ol.InternalHigh;
    pipe_settings->ol.OffsetHigh = ol.OffsetHigh;

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD WINAPI ClientProc(LPVOID)
{
    struct pipe_settings pipe_settings;
    pipe_settings.name = TEXT(DUST_TEST_PIPE_NAME);
    pipe_settings.pipe_timeout = PIPE_TEST_TIMEOUT;

    DWORD err = PipeListenForServerConnect(&pipe_settings);
    //EXPECT_EQ((DWORD)ERROR_SUCCESS, err);

    WINBOOL pipe_close_success = PipeClose(&pipe_settings);
    //EXPECT_NE(1, pipe_close_success);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ServerProc(LPVOID)
{
    struct pipe_settings pipe_settings;
    pipe_settings.name = TEXT(DUST_TEST_PIPE_NAME);
    pipe_settings.pipe_timeout = PIPE_TEST_TIMEOUT;

    DWORD err = PipeConnectToClient(&pipe_settings);
    //EXPECT_EQ((DWORD)ERROR_SUCCESS, err);

    WINBOOL pipe_close_success = PipeClose(&pipe_settings);
    //EXPECT_NE(0, pipe_close_success);

    return 0;
}



int main(void) {

    DWORD dwThreadId1;
    DWORD dwThreadId2;

    HANDLE h1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServerProc, NULL, 0, &dwThreadId1);
    HANDLE h2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientProc, NULL, 0, &dwThreadId2);

    WaitForSingleObject(h1, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(h2, INFINITE);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no *segmentation faults* in Windows. Please provide the exact error you are receiving. A handle (or any value) in a debug build, containing only byte values `0xcc` indicate uninitialized data as well.

Comment: Hmm.  That fixed it but for the life of me I can't tell what the difference is.  Look at my answer for the new function.

Comment: Yeah, you are passing uninitialized data. Time for some debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateEvent()` does not use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to represent an invalid handle, it uses `NULL` instead.  So you need to make `InitializePipeSettings()` initialize `ol.hEvent` to `NULL`:

```
void InitializePipeSettings(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    pipe_settings->hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    pipe_settings->ol.hEvent = NULL; // <-- here
    pipe_settings->ol.Internal = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.InternalHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Offset = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.OffsetHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Pointer = NULL;
}
```

And then in `PipeClose()`, you need to check each handle for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`/`NULL` before calling `CloseHandle()` on it.  And you should also have `PipeClose()` reset the handles that it closes, so that `PipeClose()` can safely be called multiple times on the same `pipe_settings`:

```
WINBOOL PipeClose(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    BOOL bResult = TRUE;
    if (pipe_settings->ol.hEvent != NULL)
    {
        bResult = bResult && CloseHandle(pipe_settings->ol.hEvent);
        pipe_settings->ol.hEvent = NULL;
    }
    if (pipe_settings->hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        bResult = bResult && CloseHandle(pipe_settings->hPipe);
        pipe_settings->hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice but the answer is that it was not liking my returning of the CloseHandle function.  I posted comments below my answer.  I'd love to give you the solution for this one but others might be confused.

Comment: Also, I did implement your NULL advice.  I just had two copies of the code and copied the old one.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution which works, but I don't know why.

```
WINBOOL PipeClose(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    bool failed = false;

    if(pipe_settings->ol.hEvent != NULL)
    {
        if(!CloseHandle(pipe_settings->ol.hEvent))
            failed = true;
    }

    if(pipe_settings->hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if(!CloseHandle(pipe_settings->hPipe))
            failed = true;
    }

    return failed ? 0 : 1;
}


void InitializePipeSettings(struct pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    pipe_settings->hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    pipe_settings->ol.hEvent = NULL;
    pipe_settings->ol.Internal = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.InternalHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Offset = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.OffsetHigh = 0;
    pipe_settings->ol.Pointer = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I know why!!  It's because I was returning that value.  Switching the order makes the CloseHandle(ol.hEvent) fail.

Comment: By using the return value of `CloseHandle()` as a direct operand of the `&&` operator in `return (CloseHandle(...) && CloseHandle(...));`, if the first `CloseHandle()` fails, the `&&` operator would skip calling the second `CloseHandle()`. It is called *short circuit evaluation*. That is why they need to be broken up into separate statements to ensure both handles attempt to close even if one of them fails.

Comment: Even if I separate them, it still fails.  WINBOOL is supposed to be 0 or non-zero.  So boolean logic should work.

Comment: The only way it can fail is if you are trying to close something that was not open to begin with. Which is why you should check for an invalid handle value BEFORE you close it, and then set it to an invalid handle value AFTER you do close it. In your original code, you are calling `PipeClose()` regardless of whether the handles are actually created, so you have to be prepared to receive invalid handles and NOT close them.

Comment: Well it's failing on an open pipe.  Even if that were true, it would fail gracefully and provide a proper error message.  Even IF I check that the pipe is open and then return CloseHandle.. I get the same issue.

Comment: CloseHandle(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); does not sigsegv.

Comment: Also, my first comment on this thread: "Switching the order makes the CloseHandle(ol.hEvent) fail."  Before that, CloseHandle on the event always worked.  After that CloseHandle on the pipe always worked and CloseHandle on the event always failed.

Comment: *"CloseHandle(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); does not sigsegv."* - This is hardly surprising, since there are no segmentation faults on Windows. Please update your question, and title, to reflect the **precise** error you are encountering.

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what i mean.  This issue is NOT an issue with closing the handle after all.